# PowerShell getting Lines which contains an IP address and save all those lines in another file

Tags: powershell

txt which have lines of logs and I only want those lines which contains the specific IP address and saves those to a new text file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use to find any IP address.

```
Get-Content file.txt | Where {$_ -match '(\d+\.){3}\d+'} | Set-Content newfile.txt
```

[Get-Content](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content?view=powershell-7) without the `-Raw` switch reads a file into an in-memory array object. `| Where` processes against each line for a value that matches one or more digits (`\d+`) followed by a `.` (`\.`). The digits plus `.` combination needs to be found three consecutive times (`{3}`) followed by one or more digits.

---

For a specific IP address, you can do the following:

```
$IPAddress = '192.98.12.5'
Get-Content file.txt | Where { $_.Contains($IPAddress) } | Set-Content newfile.txt
```

Comment: for example if the ip address is 191.98.12.

Comment: I provided an example for that